# In C#.net, how to get text in middle of line while printing?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, printdocument

I created a project in C# windows form application. I am using visual studio 2010, and .net framework version 4.0.
My project has print button.
I wrote code for print button:

```
 private void btn_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument pdoc = new PrintDocument();
        PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();

        PaperSize psize = new PaperSize("Custom", 100, 200);

        pd.Document = pdoc;
        pd.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;

        pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height = 820;

        pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width = 520;

        pdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
        DialogResult result = pd.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            PrintPreviewDialog pp = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            pp.Document = pdoc;
            result = pp.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pdoc.Print();
            }
        }
    }
```

And event hadler code for printDocument1 control

```
 private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        string s1 = "1st line text";
        string s2 = "2nd line text";
        string s3 = "3rd line text";
        Font f1 = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        Font f2 = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        Font f3 = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(s1, f1, Brushes.Black, new Point(260, 10));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(s2, f2, Brushes.Black, new Point(260, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(s3, f3, Brushes.Black, new Point(260, 30));

   }
```

I need string s1,s2,s3 in middle of line. From above code I am getting that string's 1st character starting from middle point of line. But I need whole string in middle of line. I tried all solutions given on net. But not yet got result. Please help me to find out, what I am missing. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you actually tried *all* solutions then you would have had an answer.

Consider that the start of text and end of text should be equidistant from the centre.

Comment: Measure string, draw from `(pageWidth - stringWidth) / 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(s1, f1, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, 10, e.PageBounds.Width, 30), new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center });
```

instead of point, set the actual rectangle of the area what you need to print and set the alignment

in your statement the code has to be

```
        string s1 = "1st line text";
        string s2 = "2nd line text";
        string s3 = "3rd line text";
        Font f1 = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        Font f2 = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        Font f3 = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(s1, f1, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, 10, e.PageBounds.Width, 10), new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center });
        e.Graphics.DrawString(s2, f2, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, 20, e.PageBounds.Width, 10), new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center });
        e.Graphics.DrawString(s3, f3, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, 30, e.PageBounds.Width, 10), new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center });
```